# Webpack - Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Recently updated node and NPM and now I am struggling to get my assets to compile when running my npm run dev command. I am receieving the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in \node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets\package.json
```

I've tried deleteing my package-lock and node modules folder and reinstalling using npm install but still no luck.

Can anybody please advise how to resolve, or to find out which versions of node/npm I should be using?

Here is my Package-json file.

```
{
"name": "Project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
},
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --mode=development",
    "prod": "webpack --watch --mode=production",
    "build": "webpack"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "flickity": "^2.2.1",
    "flickity-imagesloaded": "^2.0.0",
    "form-serialize": "^0.7.2",
    "html-validator": "^5.0.0",
    "lazysizes": "^4.1.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mobius1-selectr": "^2.4.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "svgxuse": "^1.2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axe-core": "^3.4.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^5.3.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
}
```

}

webpack config

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/*
 * Webpack Packages
 */
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');

module.exports = {
entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/js/app.js', './src/scss/styles.scss'],
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js/'),
    publicPath: 'dist/js/'
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    options: {
                        emitError: true,
                        emitWarnings: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

        // Styles
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            plugins: [
                                postcssPresetEnv({
                                    stage: 3,
                                    browsers: 'last 2 versions'
                                })
                            ],
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: '../css/style.css',
        allChunks: true
    })
],

node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

just input `npm update` in terminal

Comment: Could you add more explanation on how this answer would help the OP?